# Copy Matrix selecting which rows not to copy

Tags: c++

I have a problem when trying to figure out this:
 I have a matrix of 12x12, and for example I want to create a new matrix of 10x10 that's a exact copy of the first one but choosing which two columns not to copy. Is there a possible way to do so? I cant really figure it out

Comment: To make it a little bit clearer, in my 12x12 matrix i dont want to copy the columns 2 and 4, and to keep the symmetry I dont want to copy the rows 2 and 4 either.

Comment: Have you tried for loops?

Comment: @Kenny yes i have but when I tried it either or put the selected row and column in 0 or it copies some random numbers or event give a bigger matrix

Comment: So in other words, your program has bugs.  So what have you done to debug your code? --*Is there a possible way to do so?* -- You have full blown graphics, CAD programs, and other programs written in C++, and doubt whether removing two rows and columns from a matrix is possible?

Comment: Post your code. There's no good answer other than "just do it" but if you did it wrong, well, that's all I can say, unless you post the code. (your question should have a [mcve] anyway so you have to post the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I need to say, that there are roundabout 42 million possible solutions :-)

And normally I would use std::algorithms to solve the problem.

But, for the beginning, I will use many for loops to copy the data.

Because you did not inform on the type of the matrix elements, I created the matrix as a template. With whatever size you wish. Additionally I added a facility to be able to specify a variable list of rows/colums that should not be copied.

The code is commented and rather straightforward. However. If you have questions, then I am happy to answer.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// Matrix as vector of vectors
template <class T>
struct Matrix
{
       Matrix(size_t size) { matrix.resize(size); std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), [size](Columns & c) {c.resize(size); }); }
       Matrix() {}
       Matrix copyAndShrink(std::vector<size_t>& vectorsToOmit);

       // A vetcor has Columns
       using Columns = std::vector<T>;
       // ANd rows. And that will be the matrix
       std::vector<Columns> matrix{};
};


template <class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::copyAndShrink(std::vector<size_t>& vectorsToOmit)
{
    // Define resulting new destination Matrix
    Matrix<T> reducedMatrix{};
    // Iterate over all rows 
    for (size_t row=0; row< matrix.size(); ++row)  {
        // If we shall not copy, then ignore this row
        if (vectorsToOmit.end() != std::find(vectorsToOmit.begin(),vectorsToOmit.end(), row )) continue;

        // Create a new empty row in the destination matrix
        reducedMatrix.matrix.push_back(Columns());
        // Now we wan to copy the columns
        for (size_t column=0; column< matrix.size(); ++column)  {
            // But only, if this columns shall be copied
            if (vectorsToOmit.end() != std::find(vectorsToOmit.begin(),vectorsToOmit.end(), column )) continue;
            // Copy
            reducedMatrix.matrix.rbegin()->push_back(matrix[row][column]);
        }
    }
    return reducedMatrix;
}

constexpr size_t OriginalMatrixSize{12};
int main()
{
    // Define the source
    Matrix<int> m(OriginalMatrixSize);

    // fill the Matrix with some test data
    int fillCounter{0};
    for (size_t rows=0;rows<OriginalMatrixSize;++rows) 
        for (size_t columns=0;columns<OriginalMatrixSize;++columns)
            m.matrix[rows][columns] = fillCounter++;

   // Define the rows and columns that we do not want to copy 
    std::vector<size_t> vectorsToOmit{2UL,4UL};
    // Copy the source matrix to a reduced destination
    Matrix<int> reducedMatrix{m.copyAndShrink(vectorsToOmit)};

    // Show result. Print complete matrix
    for (size_t rows=0;rows<OriginalMatrixSize-vectorsToOmit.size();++rows) {
        for (size_t columns=0;columns<OriginalMatrixSize-vectorsToOmit.size();++columns) {
            std::cout << reducedMatrix.matrix[rows][columns] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Let's see if i understand the code haha. The idea is this, i have a matrix of 12x12 in which INFI are 9999, that 12x12 matrix i need to shrink it to a 10x10 by deleting two columns and rows and i need to find a hamiltonian path of that matrix if possible, if its not possible i need to find a 10x10 that has a hamiltonian path. The matrix is: (another comment)

Comment: {INFI,150 ,250 ,210 ,340 ,INFI,300 ,INFI,INFI,INFI,INFI,INFI}
{INFI,INFI,220 ,200 ,350 ,695 ,INFI,INFI,INFI,INFI,INFI,INFI}
{INFI,210 ,INFI,350 ,440 ,INFI,150 ,INFI,INFI,900 ,250 ,320}
{INFI,INFI,370 ,INFI,95  ,100 ,INFI,200 ,INFI,INFI,320 ,INFI}
{INFI,INFI,320 ,95  ,INFI,150 ,240 ,INFI,INFI,1200,INFI,INFI}
{INFI,INFI,335 ,90  ,140 ,INFI,200 ,160 ,INFI,INFI,INFI,INFI}
{INFI,290 ,145 ,INFI,240 ,200 ,INFI,120 ,INFI,INFI,450 ,380}
{INFI,INFI,200 ,195 ,330 ,160 ,110 ,INFI,60  ,470 ,80  ,90 }
And so on the other 4, but i think you got the idea :p

Comment: OK, you need integers. An you want to find the cheapest path through your array. Correct. Then, from where to where do you want to travel? And how are you allowed to travel? Left, Right, Down? Or also diagonal? Additionally, the Problem is NP hard. So brute force will not work. Many open questions. Can you edit your question and add more detailed requirements. Thanks